# Laravel 5.4: Requisição AJAX usando route com variável JS?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, route

Preciso usar uma rota do `Laravel` dentro do código de requisição AJAX. Do jeito que eu montei não da erro, mas não funciona.

Acredito que a chamada da variável (`servico`) esteja errada, por que eu setei um número manualmente desse jeito: `{{ route('getEsp',1)}}`, e funcionou perfeitamente.

```
var servico = $('#servico').val();
var url = "{{ route('getEsp',"+servico+")}}";

$.get(url, function(data)
{
     $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj)
     {
          $('#especialidades').append('<input type="checkbox" name="id_especialidade[]" value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.nomeEsp);
     });
});
```

Comment: Não vai funcionar! você deve passar a url original sem processamento do servidor

Comment: Vish, vou ter q pensar em outro jeito de passar a url então. Valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que a url gerada com `route('getEsp', ...)` é processada no servidor, enquanto a variável `servico` está disponível apenas para o JS. Um jeito de contornar isso é gerar a url da rota com algum placeholder para que o JS o substitua depois. Por exemplo:

```
var servico = $('#servico').val();
var url = "{{ route('getEsp', '_servico_') }}".replace('_servico_', servico);

$.get(url, function(data)
{
     $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj)
     {
          $('#especialidades').append('<input type="checkbox" name="id_especialidade[]" value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.nomeEsp);
     });
});
```

Para deixar mais claro o que acontece, vejamos o que é gerado pelo blade e o código entregue ao front-end.

```
// No arquivo .blade.php
var url = "{{ route('getEsp', '_servico_') }}".replace('_servico_', servico);

// O compilado do blade gera
var url = "<?php echo e(route('getEsp', '_servico_')); ?>".replace('_servico_', servico);

// O que o front-end recebe (imaginando um mapeamento para a rota)
var url = "http://www.site.com/especialidade/_servico_".replace('_servico_', servico);
```

A partir desse ponto, o JS vai efetivamente substituir o placeholder pelo valor da variável `servico` selecionada pelo usuário. Inspecione o código-fonte da página pelo browser para ver exatamente o que se passa!